# TCP transport in Proxy wso2 esb

Tags: sockets, tcp, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to send a request over TCP transport to a proxy service, when use this code to send my soap xml

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("host", port);

DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

outToServer.writeBytes("soap xml instance");

clientSocket.close();
```

it works fine and my business is continues.

But when i send two xml without closing the socket like this:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("host", port);

DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

outToServer.writeBytes("soap xml instance");

outToServer.writeBytes("another soap instance");

clientSocket.close();
```

it always throws this exception:

> TID: [0] [ESB] [2013-06-28 13:36:10,838] ERROR
>   {org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPWorker} -  Error while processing
>   TCP request through the Axis2 engine
>   {org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPWorker}
>   org.apache.axiom.om.OMException:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction
>   target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.  at
>   [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,5]
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.buildNext(OMDocumentImpl.java:135)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMNodeImpl.java:122)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:343)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenIterator.java:36)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractIterator.java:58)
>           at org.jaxen.util.DescendantAxisIterator.hasNext(DescendantAxisIterator.java:101)
>           at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultStep.evaluate(DefaultStep.java:152)
>           at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultLocationPath.evaluate(DefaultLocationPath.java:140)
>           at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultAbsoluteLocationPath.evaluate(DefaultAbsoluteLocationPath.java:113)
>           at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultXPathExpr.asList(DefaultXPathExpr.java:102)
>           at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectNodesForContext(BaseXPath.java:674)
>           at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectNodes(BaseXPath.java:213)
>           at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.evaluate(BaseXPath.java:172)
>           at org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath.stringValueOf(SynapseXPath.java:297)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.PropertyMediator.getResultValue(PropertyMediator.java:299)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.PropertyMediator.mediate(PropertyMediator.java:95)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:154)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPWorker.run(TCPWorker.java:68)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction
>   target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.  at
>   [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,5]
>           at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
>           at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
>           at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readPIPrimary(BasicStreamReader.java:3903)
>           at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2037)
>           at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.closeContentTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2886)
>           at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2629)
>           at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1062)
>           at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
>           at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
>           at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
>           at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
>           ... 25 more

I used appending '\n', "\r\n" to my message but non of them make that work.

Also i tried that used the method that explined in this link.[How to Send SOAP Messages Using TCP Transport](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/transports/tcp-transport.html) and it worked fine.

But i could not use that kind of api in my project. How can i get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to send TCP messages to ESB using a sample client but you have to make sure you send an XML element.

First make sure you have enabled transport reciver for tcp in axis2.xml (repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml)

```
<transportReceiver name="tcp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportListener" >
```

========================My Proxy Service which recives TCP messages ===========

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="TCPProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.tcp.port">6789</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.tcp.contentType">application/xml</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

==Client that send messages to TCP server ====

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient {
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 6789;
    Socket socket = null;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        String name ="Amani";
        TCPClient client = new TCPClient();
        String message = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n" +  
        "<soapenv:Header/>\n" +
        "<soapenv:Body>\n" +
        "  <p:greet xmlns:p=\"http://greet.service.amani.org\">\n" + 
        "     <in>" + name + "</in>\n" +
        "  </p:greet>\n" +
        "</soapenv:Body>\n" +
        "</soapenv:Envelope>";
        client.SendToServer("<test></test>");
        client.close();
    }

    TCPClient(String _host, int _port) throws Exception{
        host = _host;
        port = _port;
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
    }
    TCPClient() throws Exception{
        socket = new Socket(host, port);
    }
    void SendToServer(String msg) throws Exception{
        //create output stream attached to socket
        PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        //send msg to server
        outToServer.print(msg + '\n');
        outToServer.flush();
    }
    String RecieveFromServer() throws Exception{
        //create input stream attached to socket
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));
        //read line from server
        String res = inFromServer.readLine(); // if connection closes on server end, this throws java.net.SocketException 
        return res;
    }
    void close() throws IOException{
        socket.close();
    }
}
```